# Not getting JSON value when key is a variable

Tags: javascript, json

i have come across a peculiar problem. That is i can able to access the value of a JSON array when i am doing it directly with key. But it is not getting the same when key is a variable. For eg.,

```
var response = {"jpg":{"table_name":"tbl_photo"}};

alert(response.jpg.table_name);
var fileType = "jpg";
alert(response.fileType.table_name);
```

In this, the first alert is getting triggered correctly. But in the second, where we are passing the key as a variable, it is not working.

Here is the fiddle link of this, http://jsfiddle.net/aAZeT/

Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: alert(response[filetype].table_name)

Comment: @philipp It is right, but it is `fileType` and not `filetype` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For strings you need index operation i.e. [] :

```
var response = {"jpg":{"table_name":"tbl_photo"}};

alert(response.jpg.table_name);
var fileType = "jpg";
alert(response[fileType].table_name);
```